# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am new to AngularJs and try my first project into it. Using Angular.min.js and angular-route.js 1.6.9 version. While hitting the http://localhost/myAngular/login/main.html in browser getting Uncaught Error:

> [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=ReferenceError%3A%20otherwise%20is%20not%20defined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FmyAngular%2Flogin%2Fmain.html%3A32%3A2%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A44%3A390)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A279)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A418%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20we%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A1)

## main.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="Eng">
    <head>
    <title>Login Demo</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"> </script>    
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>  
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
   </body>
```

controller.js

```
  var app  = angular.module( 'mainApp', ['ngRoute'] );

  app.config( function( $routeProvider ) {

 $routeProvider
 .when( '/main', {
    template: 'Welcome User!'
    //templateUrl: 'login.html'
  })
  .when('/anotherPage', {
    template: 'Welcome User, again!'
    //templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
  })
  otherwise({

    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});

app.controller( 'loginCtrl', function( $scope, $location) {
$scope.submit = function(){
    var userName = $scope.userName;
    var password = $scope.password;

    if(userName == "admin" && password == "admin"){
        $location.path = '/dashboard';

    }
    console.log( userName +"  "+ password);
   };

    });
```

===========================================================

login.html

```
    <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div>
    <form action="/" id="myLogin">
    User Name: <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="userName"/> 
    <br>br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"/> 
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In `controller.js`, you're missing a period before `otherwise`.

Comment: Click on the link in the error message. It clearly states: `ReferenceError: otherwise is not defined`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 $routeProvider
 .when( '/main', {
    template: 'Welcome User!'
    //templateUrl: 'login.html'
  })
  .when('/anotherPage', {
    template: 'Welcome User, again!'
    //templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
  })
  .otherwise({ // <-- you were missing "." here.
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Also, try to use "angular.js" rather than `angular.min.js` , you'll get readable and easily understandable error messages

---

<sub>**Side Note:** Try to use `controller` in `$routeProvider` itself rather than writing it the way you have written in `login.html`. Refer the `config` of my plunkr</sub>

[Here is the working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4VXDA5JHIoJqbfCduWb8?p=preview)

---

#### Update

As per your new code, you need to do as below

```
    $location.path('/dashboard');
```

Refer the plunkr. I have made the respective changes in it too